# Which database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, percona

I'm a java developer, currently starting developing a hospital management system that will server patients, doctors, accountant, .... etc the system is really huge that may have 900,000 records/day, data is really growing so fast, for that i'm confusing in which database to use since i have the following options: (Percona Server(Mysql), Oracle, SQLServer), since the application will run on network with average of 45 online users.

I hope to find a good answers here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Choose a DB that fits into your software environment. If using a lot of MS software I would use SQL Server for instance

Comment: Can SQL server handle 900,000 record/day this data i will keep it for least 3 years. i'm using linux for my servers

Comment: Sure it can. That's what these DBs are for. Store a lot of data.

Comment: Since you're already on linux: postgresql seems a natural choice, it also tends to lean closely to oracle, or at least stay close to the SQL standards. Why is it not included in your options?

Comment: I'm working with MySQL (Percona) is this one good to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have been working with MySQL for 6 years then stick with it!

You don't want to add the burden of learning another database as well as having to develop your application.

If you are unsure if MySQL is up to the job then **run some tests**. Write an app that runs multiple threads inserting 1M rows and see if your servers can handle it.

I'm guessing the brand of the database you choose will be less important than the performance of the platform (machines) it is running on.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good or bad answer to this question. Basically it is as good as the DBA knowns to manage it.

If asking this question it would be wise to group a team of people well known with various systems to find out the best practice. To answer such a case, even more with very sensitive data, it is not just a simple solution which will do the trick. A thorough process of decision making is very important. Not only from a technical but also from a security and business side.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but i need to know which one of these will perform better, it just simple to figure out for such a huge solution, im working with mysql since 6 years, but i need to know that mysql will handel that much of data without killing the performance???!!!

Comment: As stated there is no possible correct answer. If you have a proven record with MySQL that would be optimal if you don't have other people to support you. You are posting a very complex businesscase without lots of answers so giving an answer which is very specific is not possible. Mainly I would focus on knowledge, that's where you can win most with databases. Try to prepare the project very well though, don't just start because that will give a mess and is a really no-go area with personal data.

Comment: Aha, I'm currently using MySQL (Percona) server but since this project will do a lot of work (inserting, updating ... etc) for millions of records & we cant delete these records since it is a medical data as i have mentioned it's a hospital information system

Answer (score 0):

As per as think your database is large you can go with oracle.but the decision also depends on the expertise of people working with you and availability of resources.